# How do I pause ALL CSS animations and resume when needed

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm making this site that plays our school hymn when the button "Play" is pressed and pauses when "Pause" is pressed. Alongside it the highlight animation 'per line' of the lyrics. However, I can't globally pause the animation. I wanted to pause the audio and the css animation but only the audio is the one that is actually paused so when I click the play button, the lyrics highlight and audio is not in sync anymore.

I've tried playing with animation-play-state in CSS but none of it worked great

Sorry if the code is long because I did 'per-line' lyrics but what I wanted to do is to pause any animations so that it is still in sync with the audio whenever I resume it.

```css
.lyrics {
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 1vw;
}

.l1.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-direction: alternate;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-delay: 12s;
 
}

.l2.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 15s;
 
}

.l3.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 18s;
 
}

.l4.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 7s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 24s;
 
}

.l5.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 29s;
 
}


@keyframes tae {
 0% {background: initial;}
 30% {background: blue;}
 60% {background: blue;}
 100% {background: initial;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<audio id="ad">
<source src = "pup.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var song = document.getElementById("ad");
 function togglePlay() {
 song.play();
 document.getElementByClassName("an").style.animationPlayState = "running"; //this is what I'm currently using in play button
}
 function togglePause() {
 song.pause();
 document.getElementByClassName("an").style.animationPlayState = "paused"; //this is for the pause button
}
</script>

<div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="bg-box">
    <img src="PUPLogo.png">
<p class="PUP">Polytechnic University of the Philippines</p>

<h1>PUP HYMN</h1>
<p class="lyrics">
<div class="l1 an">Sintang Paaralan</div>
<div class="l2 an">Tanglaw ka ng bayan</div>
<div class="l3 an">Pandayan ng isip ng kabataan</div>
<div class="l4 an">Kami ay dumating nang salat sa yaman<br></div>
<div class="l5 an">Hanap na dunong ay iyong alay<br></div>
<!--I cut the lyrics here to make it shorter-->

<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="togglePlay()" class="but" ></input>
<input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="togglePause()" class="but"></input>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loop all of elemnt with class name `an` and set `.style.animationPlayState` to each one
also use `getElementsByClassName()` to get all elements with class name `an`

```js
var song = document.getElementById("ad");

 function togglePlay() {
 song.play();
 var items=document.getElementsByClassName("an");
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].style.animationPlayState = "running";
  }
}
 function togglePause() {
 song.pause();
  var items=document.getElementsByClassName("an");
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  }
  }
```

```css
.lyrics {
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 1vw;
}

.l1.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-direction: alternate;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-delay: 12s;
 
}

.l2.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 15s;
 
}

.l3.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 18s;
 
}

.l4.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 7s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 24s;
 
}

.l5.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 29s;
 
}


@keyframes tae {
 0% {background: initial;}
 30% {background: blue;}
 60% {background: blue;}
 100% {background: initial;}
}
```

```html
<audio id="ad">
<source src = "pup.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="bg-box">
    <img src="PUPLogo.png">
<p class="PUP">Polytechnic University of the Philippines</p>

<h1>PUP HYMN</h1>
<p class="lyrics">
<div class="l1 an">Sintang Paaralan</div>
<div class="l2 an">Tanglaw ka ng bayan</div>
<div class="l3 an">Pandayan ng isip ng kabataan</div>
<div class="l4 an">Kami ay dumating nang salat sa yaman<br></div>
<div class="l5 an">Hanap na dunong ay iyong alay<br></div>
<!--I cut the lyrics here to make it shorter-->

<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="togglePlay()" class="but" />
<input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="togglePause()" class="but"/>


</div>
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't know I need a loop but it seems that it is the solution I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First there is type you need to use **getElementsByClassName** instead of **getElementByClassName**

The second note is that you have to loop through the elements when you select them by a class selector. So I wrote a loop on the elements with class "an":

```js
var song = document.getElementById("ad");
 function togglePlay() {
 song.play();
 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("an")).forEach(
    function(element, index, array) {
       element.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }
  )
  
  
}
function togglePause() {
 song.pause();
 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("an")).forEach(
   function(element, index, array) {
       element.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }
  )
}
```

```css
.lyrics {
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 1vw;
}

.l1.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-direction: alternate;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-delay: 12s;
 
}

.l2.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 15s;
 
}

.l3.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 18s;
 
}

.l4.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 7s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 24s;
 
}

.l5.an {
 animation: tae 1s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-fill-mode: alternate;
 animation-delay: 29s;
 
}


@keyframes tae {
 0% {background: initial;}
 30% {background: blue;}
 60% {background: blue;}
 100% {background: initial;}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css1.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="106">
<title>PUP HYMN</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="ad">
<source src = "pup.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="bg-box">
    <img src="PUPLogo.png">
<p class="PUP">Polytechnic University of the Philippines</p>

<h1>PUP HYMN</h1>
<p class="lyrics">
<div class="l1 an">Sintang Paaralan</div>
<div class="l2 an">Tanglaw ka ng bayan</div>
<div class="l3 an">Pandayan ng isip ng kabataan</div>
<div class="l4 an">Kami ay dumating nang salat sa yaman<br></div>
<div class="l5 an">Hanap na dunong ay iyong alay<br></div>
<!--I cut the lyrics here to make it shorter-->

<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="togglePlay()" class="but" ></input>
<input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="togglePause()" class="but"></input>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```